# Bash run rsh on multiple servers

Tags: linux, bash

I have a server list file like this:

```
xxx ServerName1 xxx
xxx ServerName2 xxx
...
```

Now I want to go to each server to rename a file from local. My Bash scripts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   server=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` # get server name
   rsh $server mv /a/b/c.txt /a/b/d.txt   # rename on the server
   echo "rename file in $server"          # print echo
done < server.txt
```

However, it only goes to the first one "SeverName1", rename the file and print the echo. It never goes to the rest of the servers and even doesn't print the echo. I don't know why that it just works for the first one.

Does anyone give me a help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let `rsh` eat the rest of your input stream -- if it does, there's nothing left to be read by the `while read` next time the loop tries to start. The easiest way to do this is to redirect its stdin from `/dev/null`:

```
rsh "$server" mv /a/b/c.txt /a/b/d.txt </dev/null
```

---

Alternately, you can loop over a FD other than 0 (note that using `awk` here is silly; you can tell bash itself to pick out only the second field from each line, which I do in the code below):

```
while read -u 3 _ server _; do              # get server name (with read)
   rsh "$server" mv /a/b/c.txt /a/b/d.txt   # rename on the server
   echo "rename file in $server"            # print echo
done 3< server.txt
```

To explain some of the points that might be less obvious:

- The `3` is the file descriptor number; it needs to match between the `-u 3` and the `3< server.txt`. You could choose to use `read _ server _ <&3` instead of relying on `read -u`, if you want your code to be compatible with shells other than bash.
- The `_`s eat fields you don't want `read` to put content into. `read _ server _` puts the first field into `_`, the second field into `server`, and 3rd and later fields into `_`.

Comment: BTW, could you explain what means for "loop over a FD other than 0"?

Comment: FD 0 is stdin, which `read` is taking input from by default (and which, thus, the `while read` loop is iterating over). In the code I show, we're reading `server.txt` via file descriptor 3, leaving stdin alone -- so when `rsh` takes contents from its stdin, it doesn't interfere with reading `server.txt`.